# Implementation of IEnumerable and IEnumerator in custom object, return the same data when called multiple times by LINQ with a different predicate

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I wanted to be able to use LINQ queries on a custom object that does not use typical collections but nevertheless stores data in a sequential manner. The object is of type `XTable` that contains a collection of `XRows` and I have the following code that implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`.

```cs
public class EnumerableXTable : IEnumerable<XRow>
{
    private readonly XTable _xTable;
    public EnumerableXTable(XTable xTable)
    {
        _xTable=xTable;
    }

    IEnumerator<XRow> IEnumerable<XRow>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new XTableEnumerator(_xTable);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new XTableEnumerator(_xTable);
    }
}

public class XTableEnumerator : IEnumerator<XRow> 
{
    private readonly XTable _xTable;
    private int _index = -1;

    public XTableEnumerator(XTable xTable)
    {
        _xTable=xTable;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _index++;
        if (_index == _xTable.Count) return false;

        _xTable.Current.RecNo = _index;
        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("IEnumerator Reset Method not implemented");
    }

    public XRow Current => _xTable.Current;
    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
}


public static EnumerableXTable AsEnumerable(this XTable xTable)
{
    return new EnumerableXTable(xTable);
}
```

If I run the below code:

```cs
XTable t = GetXTable();
var xRow1 = t.AsEnumerable().First(xRow => xRow.Get<int>("CCCIntaleId") == 462);
var xRow2 = t.AsEnumerable().First(row => row.Get<int>("CCCIntaleId") == 465);
```

`xRow1` and `xRow2` are the exact same row, and according to the predicate, they should be different. If I set breakpoints, then when I break after the first statement, `xRow1` has the correct value and if I break after the second statement, `xRow2` has the correct value and now `xRow1` is the value of `xRow2`. It looks like there is some form of deferred execution although I think that when calling `First()`, execution should be immediate. The following code returns the correct results on `recNo1` and `recNo2`:

```cs
XTable t = GetXTable();
var xRow1 = t.AsEnumerable().First(xRow => xRow.Get<int>("CCCIntaleId") == 462);
int recNo1 = xRow1.RecNo;
var xRow2 = t.AsEnumerable().First(row => row.Get<int>("CCCIntaleId") == 465);
int recNo2 = xRow2.RecNo;
```

Furthermore, if I run the same code on a `DataTable` with the same structure as follows:

```cs
var row1 = datatable.AsEnumerable().First(row => row.Field<int>("CCCIntaleId") == 462);
var row2 = dd.AsEnumerable().First(row => row.Field<int>("CCCIntaleId") == 465);
```

the results I get are as expected. Is there anything wrong on my implementation of `IEnumerator`?

Comment: So what is `_xTable.Current`?

Comment: Assigning `xRow2` cannot change `xRow1`, unless your `_xTable.Current` returns the same object *instance* each time, only properties of which change.

Comment: @shingo `_xTable.Current`  is a property that gets the XRow at the position dictated by the RecNo property.

Comment: How does it change its value by changing RecNo? Can you show the exact code?

Comment: @GSerg Why then when I ask the RecNo of XRow, I get the correct behavior? It is so bizzare.

Comment: @shingo I do not have access to that code, it is on a third-party library.

Comment: Because you are asking for `RecNo` at the moment when it's correct (after assigning `xRow1` but before assigning `xRow2`). And when you later ask it again after assigning `xRow2`, you cannot tell anymore that it would have been wrong for `recNo1` if you could call that again a second time.

Comment: @GSerg I understand, but when I set xRow1= _xTable.Current, am I not getting a reference to the XRow before it changes again when I assign xRow2? That reference should not be affected when future changes to _xTable.Current are taking place. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, provided `_xTable.Current` returns a [different *object instance*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75274504/implementation-of-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-in-custom-object-return-the-same#comment132828447_75274504) each time. Does it? Or does it return the same singleton each time, and before returning it, changes its `RecNo` property?

Comment: Can I access the library or any document? It looks like `_xTable.Current` always returns the same instance.

Comment: @GSerg that is correct. It returns the same object with a different value on RecNo. Thank you very much for the precious help.

Comment: @shingo that is correct. It returns the same object with a different value on RecNo. Thank you very much for the precious help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given in the comments. The problem was that `_xTable.Current` returns the same object everytime, with a different indexer. Thus, both xRow1 and xRow2 refer to the same object and at the end, both objects point to the values dictated by the indexer.